# Hot to add a range dashed box on a bar plot using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I've made a bar chart using Birt, but due to a change of technology, I have to use Matplotlib now. I want to know if it is possible (and how) to make a similar chart using Matplotlib, especially the range dashed square around the top 80% of the bars as in example:

[image: birt chart].

I didn't find any documentation on how to make it.

Does anybody know how to proceed?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're after here.  If it's just to add a rectangle on the plot, see the [API](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) and some [examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/artist_reference.html).

Comment: It's not just to draw a shape on the page but to automatically generate a box around the 80% of the data on the plot, in this example 82% of the population. So that the person reading the report sees clearly where is most of the data. It's an equivalent of "MarkerRangeImpl" in Birt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this.

You can use [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Rectangle) for the dashed box.

I've also moved the `spines` outwards to match the style of your plot (code taken from [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/spines_demo_dropped.html))

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

# Fake some data
x = np.array([15,25,35,45,45,45,45,45,75,75,95,150,160,170,170,1040])
y = np.arange(0.1,16.1,1)
percent = np.array([(100.*float(i)/x.sum()) for i in x])

# Create Figure and Axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Plot the bars
ax.barh(y,x)

# Move left and bottom spines outward by 5 points
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('outward', 5))
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', 5))
# Hide the right and top spines
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
# Only show ticks on the left and bottom spines
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')

# Set the axes limits and tick locations
ax.set_ylim(0,16)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

ax.set_xlim(0,1100)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))

# Add the rectangle
rect = Rectangle( (0,10), 1100, 6, linestyle = 'dashed', facecolor = 'None', clip_on=False)
ax.add_patch(rect)

# Add the percentage labels
for p,xi,yi in zip(percent,x,y):
    ax.text(xi+5,yi+0.2,'{:2.0f}\%'.format(p))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok thank you very much for you example tom, I see now how it works. I didn't know width and height of Rectangle were referring to the actual axis scale.

Comment: It is using the default `transform`, which is `ax.transData`. If you change the transform to `ax.transAxes`, you can use fractional axes coordinates, for example: `rect = Rectangle( (0,0.625), 1, 0.375, linestyle = 'dashed', facecolor = 'None', clip_on=False, transform = ax.transAxes)` gives the same box as above